# Uploading image with url in Codeigniter(with csv file)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to upload image with url. It is working properly. Image can be uploaded properly but if image is already exist then it over-write the file.
Here is my code -

```
    $url=$d[1];
    $name = basename($url);
    $my_location='././assets/temp_upload/';
    if (!defined('IMAGE_DIR')) define('IMAGE_DIR', $my_location);   
    if(!$img = file_get_contents($url))
    { 
     die('Getting that file failed');
    }
    if(!$f = fopen(IMAGE_DIR.'/'.$name, 'w'))
     { 
      die('Opening file for writing failed'); 
     }
    if (fwrite($f, $img) === FALSE)
    { 
     die('Could not write to the file'); 
    }
    fclose($f);
```

I just want, if image file is already exist then it's name should be changed so that image will not over-write.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Rename the image name with milliseconds then it's will work fine also if you never want to keep the old image just unlink it

Comment: Codeigniter has own built in upload library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: As @wolfgang1983 said, you have to refer the codeigniter's file upload library. There is ```overwrite``` option in file upload config, you need to set it ```true```.

Comment: Actually I am using csv file to upload data including images.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I cant use Codeigniter's built in upload library. Image may already stored on server. I have to upload that image on my folder by using the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, you can add a random string to the end of the image file name.

```
$name_temp = basename($url);
$my_location='././assets/temp_upload/';
if (file_exists($my_location.''.$name_temp)) {
  $fileinfo = pathinfo($url);
  $name=$fileinfo['filename'].'_'.rand(1,10000).''.$fileinfo['extension'];
}
else
{
  $name=$name_temp;
}
```

You can customize this as per your need.

Comment: @ Bikram. Thanks for answer. This is working properly.